# Why am I getting compiler errors, "illegal start of expression"?

Tags: java

The "illegal start of expression" errors are with these 3 statements in TestPayroll class.  Thanks in advance.

```
private String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};

private double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};

private double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};
```

TestPayroll.java below:

```
/**
This program contains a Payroll class that has private data members for an employee's full name, hourly rate pay, number of hours worked, and total pay for the week. There is an array of 3 Payroll objects, which is instantiated manually with the number of hours each employee worked.  The program displays the amount of gross pay each employee has earned.  
*/

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestPayroll {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    private String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
    private double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};
    private double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};

    //Payroll object
    Payroll calcPay = new Payroll(name, weeksPay);

    //Display weekly pay
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This week's pay for " + name[0].getName + " is " + payroll.getWeeksPay() +"\n" + "This week's pay for " + name[1].getName + " is " + payroll.getWeeksPay() + "\n" + "This week's pay for " + name[2].getName + " is " + payroll.getWeeksPay());

}   

}

public class Payroll {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    private String name;
    private double payRate;
    private double hrsWorked;
    private double weeksPay;

    //default constructor
    public Payroll() {
        this.name = name;
        this.payRate = payRate;
        this.hrsWorked = hrsWorked;
        this.weeksPay = weeksPay;
    }

    //Payroll constructor
    public Payroll(String name, double payRate, double hrsWorked, double weeksPay) {
        this.name = name;
        this.payRate = payRate;
        this.hrsWorked = hrsWorked;
        this.weeksPay = weeksPay;
    }

    //return name
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //set name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //return pay rate
    public double getPayRate() {
        return payRate;
    }

    //set pay rate
    public void setPayRate(double payRate) {
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    //return hours worked for the week
    public double getHrsWorked() {
        return hrsWorked;
    }

    //set hours worked for the week
    public void setHrsWorked(double hrsWorked) {
        this.hrsWorked = hrsWorked;
    }

    //find week's pay
    public double getWeeksPay(double weeksPay) {
        double weeksPay = payRate * hrsWorked;
        return weeksPay;
    }   

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These belong in the class not in a method:

```
    private String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
    private double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};
    private double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};
```

or you can remove the private keyword in that case they will be local variables in your `main` method.

Your `Payroll` class has its code in a `main` method. This will not compile. Remove your code from the `main` method and put it in the class.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you, & moved those three lines:

Comment: I moved those three lines to after:  
public class TestPayroll {


Now the 1st of 81 errors is, "TestPayroll.java:20: error: cannot find symbol Payroll calcPay = new Payroll(name, weeksPay);"
(One of the requirements is to have private data members for an employee's full name, hourly rate pay, number of hours worked, and total pay for the week.)

Comment: I believe that you did not import the Payroll class.

Comment: Payroll & TestPayroll are in the same folder.

Comment: I think that you should use an IDE like Eclipse. It will help tremendously.

Comment: Thank you. I have it in Netbeans now. Getting an error "Class, interface, or enum expected" on last curly brace in Payroll class.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and time with me. I really appreciate it. May GOD bless you.

Comment: I do not believe in God. I believe in Satan.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33375/discussion-between-grafica-and-adam-arold)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

is a method, not a class definition. As a result, it cannot hold members, and that means that adding a member scope `private` to `String name` is nonsense to the compiler.

Now, if you had the following

```
public class Something {

  private String name;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     ...
  }

}
```

it would be a different story.  Now `String name` is part of the class definition, not the static method.  Since it is a *member of the class*, it can have a *class exposure scope*.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
private double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};
private double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};
```

should be, just:

```
String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};
double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};
```

Remove `private` to make them as local variables;

(OR)

If you want as instance variable, move them directly inside class.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but those look like they should be *fields*, not local variables.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but suggest giving more emphasis to the making-them-fields alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `private` modifier on each of those 3 lines. Or if you meant for them to be instance variables, move them out of the `main` method. It depends on your intent.

Comment: Thanks. I moved them out of main method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the modifier `private` :

```
String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};
double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};
```

It is an illegal modifier for local variables . Local variables can have only `final` keyword preceding its declaration.  Refer [JLS 14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `private` modifier in a method is not legal.

The `private`, `public` and `protected` modifiers are used to control variables access among classes, not among methods. A variable declared in a method, it is accessible only in the scope of the method itself.

You can deepen your knowledge of variable modifiers by reading the [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) in the official Java tutorial by Oracle.